# What is the g++ flag that permits undefined references in shared libraries?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dylib

I remember reading exactly what this flag is at some point on the internet but now I forget.

I'm writing a shared library and I want my library to permit undefined references. That way, whoever uses my library has to link against it **and** link against it's dependancies. What flag on g++ permits this? Or maybe is it a linker flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can only be a linker flag... and then, it depends on what linker you're using.
On Linux (and probably BSD, at least [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ld(1))) this should be the default behaviour. Not on Mac though.

From the [GNU `ld` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

```
--allow-shlib-undefined
--no-allow-shlib-undefined
          Allows or disallows undefined symbols in shared libraries.
          This switch is similar to --no-undefined except that it determines
          the behaviour when the undefined symbols are in a shared library rather
          than a regular object file. It does not affect how undefined symbols in
          regular object files are handled.

          The default behaviour is to report errors for any undefined symbols
          referenced in shared libraries if the linker is being used to create an
          executable, but to allow them if the linker is being used to create a
          shared library.
```

From the [Apple `ld` man page](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/ld.1.html#sect11):

```
-undefined treatment  
         Specifies how undefined symbols are to be treated. Options
         are: error, warning, suppress, or dynamic_lookup.  The
         default is error.
```

Comment: Ah, you're right... The article I was reading was about Linux and not Mac. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

Simply do not link your shared library with its dependent libraries, that's all.

By default, when linking a shared library, undefined references are permitted. Now, if you explicitly link your shared library with its dependencies, the runtime loader will automatically load those dependencies. If you do not explicitly link your shared library with its dependencies, linking with your shared library will require linking with its dependencies, in order to unresolve all undefined references.